# Rebuild MySQL query to stay below MAX_JOIN_SIZE rows

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization, left-join

I have a SQL query which fails (most of the times) because of too many joined rows. The error provided by MySQL is `The SELECT would examine more than MAX_JOIN_SIZE rows; check your WHERE and use SET SQL_BIG_SELECTS=1 or SET MAX_JOIN_SIZE=# if the SELECT is okay`. I know I can avoid the error by setting the mentioned variables SQL_BIG_SELECTS and MAX_JOIN_SIZE, but I feel like this isn't the right way and pushes the problem only a bit in the future, because the join count might grow in the future.

The facts: I have an event planning tool which assigns users (=workers) to certain tasks. The tables are `users` (userid,username) [ID and name], `tasks` (taskid,task,start,end) [ID, task name, start as timestamp, end as timestamp] and `userassignment` (id,userid,taskid,deleted) [ID, user assigned to a task, the task, is the assignment still valid).

The exact table definition is like this:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
 userid INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 username VARCHAR(250),
 PRIMARY KEY (userid)
);

CREATE TABLE tasks (
 taskid INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 task VARCHAR(250),
 start INT,
 end INT,
 PRIMARY KEY (taskid),
 INDEX USING BTREE (start),
 INDEX USING BTREE (end)
);

CREATE TABLE userassignment (
 id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 userid INT,
 taskid INT,
 deleted TINYINT,
 PRIMARY KEY (id),
 INDEX USING BTREE (userid),
 INDEX USING BTREE (userid),
 UNIQUE KEY `usertasks` (  `userid` ,  `taskid` )
);
```

I need to know, which users are assigned and on which main days of the event (day 1, day 2, day 3) they're assigned.

My query looks like this:

```
SELECT
    u.userid,
    u.username,
    COUNT(ua.id) AS count_all,
    dayone.c AS count_one,
    daytwo.c AS count_two,
    daythree.c AS count_three
FROM
    users AS u
INNER JOIN
    userassignment AS ua ON ua.userid = u.userid AND ua.deleted = 0
INNER JOIN
    tasks AS t ON ua.taskid = t.taskid

    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT
            u.userid,
            COUNT(ua.id) AS c
        FROM
            users AS u
        INNER JOIN
            userassignment AS ua ON
            ua.userid = u.userid AND
            ua.deleted = 0
        INNER JOIN
            tasks AS t ON
            ua.taskid = t.taskid
        WHERE
            t.start > UNIX_TIMESTAMP("2014-08-01 00:00:00") AND
            t.start < UNIX_TIMESTAMP("2014-08-02 00:00:00")
        GROUP BY
            u.userid
    ) AS dayone ON dayone.userid = u.userid

    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT
            u.userid,
            COUNT(ua.id) AS c
        FROM
            users AS u
        INNER JOIN
            userassignment AS ua ON
            ua.userid = u.userid AND
            ua.deleted = 0
        INNER JOIN
            tasks AS t ON
            ua.taskid = t.taskid
        WHERE
            t.start > UNIX_TIMESTAMP("2014-07-31 00:00:00") AND
            t.start < UNIX_TIMESTAMP("2014-08-01 00:00:00")
        GROUP BY
            u.userid
    ) AS daytwo ON daytwo.userid = u.userid

    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT
            u.userid,
            COUNT(ua.id) AS c
        FROM
            users AS u
        INNER JOIN
            userassignment AS ua ON
            ua.userid = u.userid AND
            ua.deleted = 0
        INNER JOIN
            tasks AS t ON
            ua.taskid = t.taskid
        WHERE
            t.start > UNIX_TIMESTAMP("2014-08-02 00:00:00") AND
            t.start < UNIX_TIMESTAMP("2014-08-04 00:00:00")
        GROUP BY
            u.userid
    ) AS daythree ON daythree.userid = u.userid

WHERE
    t.start > UNIX_TIMESTAMP("2014-07-31 00:00:00") AND
    t.start < UNIX_TIMESTAMP("2014-08-04 00:00:00")
GROUP BY
    u.userid
ORDER BY
    username ASC
```

First I select all users which have an assignment in one of the three days (there are about six time more users in the DB than assigned to a task), then I left join the assigned users of every of the three days.

So, is there a way to rebuild the query to join fewer rows? I only need to know, who is assigned on which day, not the number of assignments.

I already tried to UNION several queries but this was unsuccessful.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/767d6/3/0)

An EXPLAIN of the real query (not in the SQL Fiddle) is:

```
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    filtered    Extra
1   PRIMARY t   range   PRIMARY,start   start   5   NULL    120 100.00  Using where; Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort
1   PRIMARY ua  ref usertasks,userid,taskid taskid  2   db1154575-helfer.t.id   2   100.00  Using where
1   PRIMARY u   eq_ref  userid  userid  2   db1154575-helfer.ua.userid  1   100.00   
1   PRIMARY <derived2>  ALL NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    152 100.00   
1   PRIMARY <derived3>  ALL NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    94  100.00   
1   PRIMARY <derived4>  ALL NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    147 100.00   
4   DERIVED t   range   PRIMARY,start   start   5   NULL    53  100.00  Using where; Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort
4   DERIVED ua  ref usertasks,userid,taskid taskid  2   db1154575-helfer.t.id   2   100.00  Using where
4   DERIVED u   eq_ref  userid  userid  2   db1154575-helfer.ua.userid  1   100.00  Using index
3   DERIVED t   range   PRIMARY,start   start   5   NULL    21  100.00  Using where; Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort
3   DERIVED ua  ref usertasks,userid,taskid taskid  2   db1154575-helfer.t.id   2   100.00  Using where
3   DERIVED u   eq_ref  userid  userid  2   db1154575-helfer.ua.userid  1   100.00  Using index
2   DERIVED t   range   PRIMARY,start   start   5   NULL    44  100.00  Using where; Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort
2   DERIVED ua  ref usertasks,userid,taskid taskid  2   db1154575-helfer.t.id   2   100.00  Using where
2   DERIVED u   eq_ref  userid  userid  2   db1154575-helfer.ua.userid  1   100.00  Using index
```

Comment: The surrogate PK (id) in the assignments table appears to be redundant.

Comment: @Downvoter: I'd really like to know why this question gets downvoted without any comment one and a half years after posting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should return the same result set:

```
    SELECT u.userid, u.username,
           COUNT(ua.id) AS count_all,
           SUM(case when t.start > UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2014-08-01 00:00:00') AND
                         t.start < UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2014-08-02 00:00:00')
                    then 1 else 0
                end) as count_one,
           SUM(case when t.start > UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2014-07-31 00:00:00') AND
                         t.start < UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2014-08-01 00:00:00')
                    then 1 else 0
                end) as count_two,
           SUM(case when t.start > UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2014-08-02 00:00:00') AND
                         t.start < UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2014-08-04 00:00:00')
                    then 1 else 0
                end) as count_three
    FROM users u LEFT JOIN
         userassignment ua 
         ON ua.userid = u.userid AND
            ua.deleted = 0 LEFT JOIN
         tasks t
         ON ua.taskid = t.taskid
    WHERE ua.deleted = 0 AND
          t.start > UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2014-07-31 00:00:00') AND
          t.start < UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2014-08-04 00:00:00')
    GROUP BY u.userid
    ORDER BY u.username;
```

Your formulation is a bit tricky.  The outer joins are filter out any user whose assignments are always deleted, for instance.  And the date periods are overlapping (I'm not sure if that is intentional, but it is how the query is structured).

Perhaps this simpler query will not exceed internal limits.

Comment: Looks very good! I will test it later. `filter out any user whose assignments are always deleted` --> If the assignments are *always* deleted for a user, he shouldn't be listed, that's fine. `the date periods are overlapping` --> I mixed up day 1 and day 2, but I don't think they overlap. But they don't include tasks which start at midnight (which doesn't occur).

Answer (score 2):

So, is all that really just a long-winded way of saying this...

```
SELECT u.*
     , DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(t.start)) dt
     , COUNT(t.taskid) total
  FROM users u
  LEFT 
  JOIN userassignment ut
    ON ut.userid = u.userid
   AND ut.deleted = 0
  LEFT
  JOIN tasks t 
    ON t.taskid = ut.taskid
 GROUP
    BY u.userid
     , DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(t.start))
```

In the example above, you can change `COUNT(t.taskid)` to COUNT(CASE WHEN x = 'y' THEN z END) or SUM(CASE...

Comment: Yes, I think you're right :) I'd need to rewrite it to have the layout of my query.

Comment: Why? Why not just turn your head/rotate your monitor?

Comment: The SQL result is used in another function outside of MySQL. And if I change the layout of the result, I'd also have to change this function.

Comment: If it was me, I'd change the function - but if you want a pivot, see the note at the end of my answer.